# AntDesign deselect Radio Group checked button

Tags: reactjs, antd

The simple question is, how to deselect a button from a `Radio Group` of `Radio Buttons`?

I am building controls for my app, where the user can select different speeds for an animation.

I have Radio Group with 5 buttons for different preset speed modes:

```
const speedPresets = [
  { label: "Very fast", value: { mode: VERY_FAST, speed: 50, increments: 1 } },
  { label: "Fast", value: { mode: FAST, speed: 100, increments: 0.5 } },
  { label: "Normal", value: { mode: NORMAL, speed: 100, increments: 0.1 } },
  { label: "Slow", value: { mode: SLOW, speed: 100, increments: 0.0007 } },
  { label: "Very slow", value: { mode: VERY_SLOW, speed: 200, increments: 0.0003 } },
];
```

Rendered:

```
<Radio.Group size="small" onChange={handleSetSpeedOnChange}>
  <Space direction="vertical">
    {speedPresets.map(({ label, value }, index) => (
      <Radio.Button
        key={`rbs${index}${label}`}
        value={value}
        {...(speedMode === MANUAL && { checked: false })}
      >
        {label}
      </Radio.Button>
    ))}
  </Space>
</Radio.Group>
```

`speedMode` is a variable that tracks the current speed mode which can be one of 6:

```
VERY_FAST, FAST, NORMAL, SLOW, VERY_SLOW, MANUAL
```

The presets contain all modes without the MANUAL mode, since they are presets.

I have a different set of controls elsewhere on the page that can change the speed manually with finer controls.

What I want to do is simple, once the user clicks on any of the "fine tuning" controls, the mode is set to `MANUAL` (I got that working) and whatever Radio Button was selected, it must be deselected (since now other controls are in charge).

I have tried using

```
{...(speedMode === MANUAL && { checked: false })}
```

To give `checked=false` prop to all radio buttons, if the mode is `MANUAL`, but whatever radio button was last selected, stays selected.

If I log the condition:

```
console.log(speedMode !== MANUAL && { checked: false })
```

It works as expected and outputs `{ checked: false }` object on the console, when mode is `MANUAL`, otherwise logs just `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The control should be on `Radio.Group` not on `Radio.Button` and when there's a programmatically change, `setState` will always involve. Try this:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

const handleSetSpeedOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log('radio checked', e.target.value);
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
    //change speedMode value here
}

<Radio.Group 
  size="small"
  onChange={handleSetSpeedOnChange}
  value={speedMode === MANUAL ? null : selectedValue} // <- deselect logic here
>
  <Space direction="vertical">
    {speedPresets.map(({ label, value }, index) => (
      <Radio.Button
        key={`rbs${index}${label}`}
        value={value}            
      >
        {label}
      </Radio.Button>
    ))}
  </Space>
</Radio.Group>
```

A simple example here:

[image: Edit]